# TinyMCE (Image Manager): How to force client to upload via "basic upload"

Tags: tinymce, mcimagemanager

as you may already know, ImageManager has 3 ways to upload files (Flash / Silverlight / Basicupload).
If you have silverlight installed on your pc, it'll use it. Same for flash ect..

**Is there a way to force the plugin to use only the Basic upload ?**
I can't find such option in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a trick to disable any of them by removing values in one of the files. If you go to the file imagemanager/pages/im/js/upload.js there should be a method called initPlupload and in that a line like "runtimes : 'gears,silverlight,flash'," Get rid of silverlight and flash and then it should always default to the basic uploader.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=22335